# validating input of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fire a trigger checking input of the "shift_name" column. I need to have only 3 values for that. I tried below code and got no error but trigger is not working either.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shift (
shift_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
section_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
week_day VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "please write one of the 
days of week",
shift_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "please write one of 
Morning, Afternoon, or Night",
personnel_need INT) AUTO_INCREMENT = 3101;


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER "test_before_insert" 
ON shift FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.shift_name IN ("Morning", "Afternoon", "Night"))
THEN
-- Set the error message
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'please wright one of the Morning, Afternoon, 
or Night';
END IF;
END; $$
-- Reset delimiter
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I think you should have "not in" instead of in. But instead of this trigger, I think you should be looking at check constraints.

Comment: On a side note: Stay consitent and standard-compliant with your quotes. Only use single quotes for string literals: `IN ('Morning', 'Afternoon' ...`, `'please write one of the 
days of week'`. And do you really want this default string instead of null? That seems weird.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified table structure and the trigger for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shift (
  shift_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  section_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  week_day VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'please write one of the days of week',
  shift_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'please write one of Morning, Afternoon, or Night',
  personnel_need INT
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 3101;



/* The Trigger*/

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER test_before_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON shift 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF (NEW.shift_name NOT IN ('Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Night')) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Please write one of the Morning, Afternoon, or Night';
  END IF;
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```